# Comparing data sets of varying sizes

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, mean, sample-size

Suppose I want to compare the similarity of 2 data sample sets (a and b).

Data set a has 13 data points and data set b has 1000 data points.

For each data set, I compute a metric z (like the mean).

I'm looking for a weight function for the metric z that goes from 0 to 1 based on the number of points in the data set. This weight is how confident I am in the estimated metric.

If there are few data points in the data set, the weight should be close to zero. If there are a 1000 data points the weight should very close to 1.

Comment: Define "similar"...

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty useless function, but this function obviously satisfies the little conditions you have given:

$$
z(N):=\frac{1}{1+|N-1000|}
$$

But IMHO you should reconsider what you are doing, and explain it better.